# Function & Cursor HELP ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, cursors

Trying to get this output:

[image]

```
   SELECT E.ID_EMPLEADO ,E.APEMPPAT  , E.ID_JEFE   
     FROM EMPLEADOS E
     WHERE E.ID_SUCURSAL=4
     CONNECT BY PRIOR E.ID_EMPLEADO = E.ID_JEFE ;
```

with this function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EMPLO_FUN
(V_EMPL_SUC IN EMPLEADOS.ID_SUCURSAL%TYPE) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    V_NEMP_HASR EMPLEADOS.ID_EMPLEADO%TYPE;
    V_DEP_HASR  EMPLEADOS.APEMPPAT%TYPE;
    V_JURIS_HASR EMPLEADOS.ID_JEFE%TYPE;
CURSOR C1
IS 
   SELECT E.ID_EMPLEADO ,E.APEMPPAT, E.ID_JEFE  
     INTO  V_NEMP_HASR, V_DEP_HASR, V_JURIS_HASR 
     FROM EMPLEADOS E
     WHERE E.ID_SUCURSAL=V_EMPL_SUC
     CONNECT BY PRIOR E.ID_EMPLEADO = E.ID_JEFE ;
   BEGIN

   OPEN c1;
    FETCH c1 INTO V_NEMP_HASR, V_DEP_HASR, V_JURIS_HASR;


   CLOSE c1;
   RETURN V_NEMP_HASR;
    RETURN V_DEP_HASR;
    RETURN V_JURIS_HASR;
    END;

 SELECT EMPLO_FUN (4) FROM DUAL;
```

I know that functions mostly return one value serching found that i can use a cursor to get multiples values, but i need help,I think some loop sentence is missing

Comment: Why do you need a function? If you want to hide the logic to query your table, you can build a view and then get your result with something like `select * from yourView where ID_SUCURSAL = 4`; is this an option?

Comment: No, I can only use a function, in fact I am trying to make a more complex Hierarchical query, is for a school project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Query you are returning `VARCHAR2` which will return only a value. Instead you should return `SYS_REFCURSOR`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EMPLO_FUN (V_EMPL_SUC IN EMPLEADOS.ID_SUCURSAL%TYPE) 
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
    V_MYRESULT SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN V_MYRESULT FOR
        SELECT E.ID_EMPLEADO ,E.APEMPPAT, E.ID_JEFE  
        FROM EMPLEADOS E
        WHERE E.ID_SUCURSAL=V_EMPL_SUC
        CONNECT BY PRIOR E.ID_EMPLEADO = E.ID_JEFE ;

RETURN V_MYRESULT;
END;
```

Then `SELECT EMPLO_FUN (4) FROM DUAL;` should give you the expected result.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, but why print everything in a continuous line?